# Error pulling SQL docker image

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am getting the following error while pulling the SQL Server images.

> failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: BackupWrite \?\D:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\4b07a8bc3a32d6e84698d7bb6a36d186f383afe00a113efde7bb20b7e1425509\Files\Documents and Settings: Incorrect function.

Due to disk space issue on my `C:\` I edited the `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` and add following entry:

```
“graph”: “D:\ProgramData\Docker”
```

to use D:\ as default image location.

Can you please help to resolve the error?

Thanks

Comment: Have you been able to pull other images after changing your data directory to D:? Also, what type of file system do you have on D:?

Comment: Thank for the  reply.  No I didn't try any other  inage. It is an usb drive formated as ntfs file system.